# Use a list or array in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to store information for 6 items and their respective length, width and cost values and then work out some values based on user input.

With the help of jcusick, I have now the code below.

I now need help for the items marked in the comments (#).

You do not need to write the complete code - pointing in right direction is perfect.

So far I have:

```
cost = {}
cost['Themon'] = 450
cost['Larrec'] = 700
cost['Medrec'] = 500
cost['Parallel'] = 825
cost['Suncatch'] = 400
cost['Chantran'] = 975

length = {}
length['Themon'] = 3.2
length['Larrec'] = 3.4
length['Medrec'] = 2.1
length['Parallel'] = 5
length['Suncatch'] = 3
length['Chantran'] = 9

width = {}
width['Themon'] = 2.3
width['Larrec'] = 3
width['Medrec'] = 2
width['Parallel'] = 4
width['Suncatch'] = 3
width['Chantran'] = 6

area = {}
area['Themon'] = 1 # how do i calculate the area (l*w) by referencing the lenght and width dictionary 
area['Larrec'] = 1
area['Medrec'] = 1
area['Parallel'] = 1
area['Suncatch'] = 1
area['Chantran'] = 1

#menu
ans=True
while ans:
    print("""
    Enter 1. to find cheapest garden deck 
    Enter 2. to display the names of garden decks over a certain lenght
    Enter 3. to display the number of garden decks that are available over a certain area
    Enter 4. to quit
    """)
    ans=input("What option would you like? ")
    if ans=="1":
        print (min(cost, key=cost.get))
    elif ans=="2":
        input_length = input("\n Please enter minimum deck length between 2 and 15 metres")
        print # i need to display names of the decks greater than the user input length
    elif ans=="3":
        input_area = input("\n Please enter deck area in metres squared between 4 and 80")
        print # i need to display the number of garden decks that are greater that the user input area
    elif ans=="4":
        print("\n Thank you for using Penny's Decking")
    else:
        print("\n Not a valid choice")
```

Comment: *"I think I have stored the data incorrectly"* - what makes you think that? Why do you think an array would be any better? Please see [ask].

Comment: Re: indentation - I have it correctly indented in python, but had difficulty in pasting it here.

Comment: @user6820046 paste the code into the editor, select the entire code block then press the `{}` button, for general help editing click on the `?` button in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might consider creating a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for each of the variables your are interested in (length, width, cost). Then you could always query the specific dictionary depending on what the user answers:

```
cost = {}
cost['Themon'] = 450
cost['Larrec'] = 700
...
print (min(cost, key=cost.get))
# 'Themon'
```

Comment: My notes states store deck information as real or string ? Could I do that or should I use dictionary as you suggested ?

Comment: It sounds like your confusing a data _type_ with a data _structure_. A dictionary is a structure to store your information. How you input that information is up to you. In my example the structure used is a `dictionary`, and the keys are of type `string` and the values are of type `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have amended the code but I get a syntax error, I have typed the following in a new widow :- cost = {}
cost['Themon'] = 450
cost['Larrec'] = 700
cost['Medrec'] = 500
cost['Parallel'] = 825
cost['Suncatch'] = 400
cost['Chantran'] = 975

print min(cost, key=cost.get)

Comment: For `print` statements in Python 3.x, I forgot you have to wrap the statement in parenthesis; I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. Can I please ask another few questions, for input 2 and 3 I need to ask the user another input, how do I do that ? I now have 4 dictionary lists:-  cost, length, width and area, how can I work out the area by referencing dictionary length and width ? Thanks again. How can I upload my updated code - can I edit my main post and update it there ?

Comment: Yes, you can edit your original post. For asking user input, read up on the [input](https://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input) function.

Comment: Thanks, I have managed to get another input, I need to display decks over a certain length (user input) what function do I use for that (greater or equal to) ?

Comment: I have updated the main post, would you mind please having another look at it and help me with the questions in the comments please.

Answer (score 1):

I think pandas might be overkill for a small piece of code like this. For your particular example, arrays would be a faster storage method. I would go so far as to say, though, that a list is probably the more pythonic way to handle this particular scale. Your performance won't be terribly affected either way here, and it's slightly more readable now, rather than using an array.

For further reading, sometimes a namedtuple can be helpful in larger scale examples in which you keep, and access, records:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into Pandas and implement this more specifically using  DataFrames as they are perfect for what you are doing. Like mentioned by the other guys. Make sure your indentations are formatted correctly. If you don't want to use DataFrames which imho are perfect for what you are doing. I would suggest creating a dictionary of values and referencing them.